# Basic Play framework routing and web sockets example

Tags: scala, playframework, websocket, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to learn how to use web sockets in Play 2.1, and I'm having trouble getting the web socket URL to work with my app's routing configuration.  I started with a new Play application and the [Play framework documentation on websockets](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaWebSockets).

Here is my `conf/routes`:

```
# Home page
GET   /               controllers.Application.index

# Websocket test site
GET   /wstest         controllers.Application.wstest
```

Then I added the `wstest` function to my controller class:

```
object Application extends Controller {

  def index = Action {
    Ok(views.html.index("Websocket Test"))
  }

  def wstest = WebSocket.using[String] { request =>
    // Log events to the console
    val in = Iteratee.foreach[String](println).mapDone { _ =>
      Logger.info("Disconnected")
    }

    // Send a single 'Hello!' message
    val out = Enumerator("Hello!")

    (in, out)
  }
}
```

However, so far, I can only access the websocket with the URL `ws://localhost:9000/wstest`  (using the sample code at [websocket.org/echo.html](http://www.websocket.org/echo.html)).  I was looking at the `sample/scala/websocket-chat` app that comes with the Play framework, and it uses the routing configuration file to reference the websocket, like this:

```
var WS = window['MozWebSocket'] ? MozWebSocket : WebSocket
var chatSocket = new WS("@routes.Application.chat(username).webSocketURL()")
```

I tried replacing my websocket URL with `@routes.Application.wstest.webSocketURL()` and `@routes.Application.wstest`.  The first one doesn't compile.  The second one compiles, but the client and server don't exchange any messages.

How can I use my Play routing configuration to access this websocket?  What am I doing wrong here?

---

**Edit**

Here is a screenshot of my compilation error, "Cannot find any HTTP Request Header here":

[image: compilation-error]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without the compiler error it's hard to guess what might be the problem.

Either you have to use parens because of the implicit request, i.e. `@routes.Application.wstest().webSocketURL()`, or you have no implicit request in scope which is needed for the webSocketURL call.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  I added a screenshot of the compilation error.

Comment: Yeah in that case, the implicit request is missing in the template, just add another parameter list with `(implicit request: RequestHeader)`.

Answer (score 3):

Marius is right that there was no implicit request in scope.  Here's how to get it in scope:

Update the `index` function in the controller:

```
def index = Action { implicit request =>
  Ok(views.html.index("Websocket Test"))
}
```

Add the request as a curried parameter to `index.scala.html`:

```
@(message: String)(implicit request: RequestHeader)

@main(message) {

<script>
    var output;
    function init() {
        output = document.getElementById("output");
        testWebSocket();
    }
    function testWebSocket() {
        websocket = new WebSocket("@routes.Application.wstest.webSocketURL()");
    .
    .
    .
```

And now the `RequestHeader` is in scope.